# What does "count in gene set" mean?

Tags: bioinformatics, proteins, drosophila, biological-networks

I am trying to understand the analysis generated by STRING. 
In analysis for biological processes table, there is a column titled "count in gene set." This gives a value for example "68 of 498".

[image: Table]

What does this refer to?

Answer (score 3):

It means the software has 4753 genes it has labeled with "biological regulation" and the short list you gave has 45 of those genes.  That is a little higher than you might expect by chance if you'd given a random gene list of the same size.

Comment: 2.94e-06 FDR suggests to me it is significantly higher than you might expect by chance.